# Find value of a, b and c such that X^a * Y^b * Z^c is closest to N and a+b+c is mimimum

Tags: algorithm

`X`, `Y` and `Z` are three positive integers. I have to find value of `a`, `b` and `c` such that `X^a * Y^b * Z^c` is closest to some given number `N` and `a+b+c` is minimum (`a`, `b` and `c` are positive integers).

**Edit**: My current solution is to iterate over X, Y and Z raised to powers starting from 1. Compute the product of these terms, compare with previous best result and accordingly update the value of a, b and c. A python snippet of this approach is pasted below. I am assuming that X, Y and Z are integers greater than 1.

```
def foo(X, Y, Z, N):
    res = a = b = c = -1

    for i in range(1, int(math.log(N)/math.log(X))):
        for j in range(1, int(math.log(N)/math.log(Y))):
            for k in range(1, int(math.log(N)/math.log(Z))):
                product = pow(X, i) * pow(Y, j) * pow(Z, k)
                if product > N:
                    break
                if product > res:
                    res = product
                    a = i
                    b = j
                    c = k

    return a, b, c
```

This approach is giving me correct result for small values of X, Y and Z but I am not sure if it will work for all values. Is there anything I'm missing or any other approach with better complexity.

Comment: I wonder if https://math.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for this question?

Comment: This was asked as a coding question. I don't think it's suitable for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are `a,b,c` integers too?

Comment: Yes they are positive integers

Comment: In order to code something, you have to have an idea about the solution first. This is not a coding, but a math / algorithmic question.

Comment: Are X, Y and Z also positive integers ?

Comment: What do we do if faced with a choice (1) get a smaller sum for a+b+c or (2) get closer to N? Which do we choose?

Comment: @Prashant I made that comment before the edit. With that edit, I agree, this is the right place for this question

Comment: @גלעד ברקן getting closer to N should be given preference

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems fine. You won't be doing that many iterations anyway because of how fast powers grow and reach N in log steps.

A few optimizations are that you dont have to compute the product every time. Have a single number and keep manipulating that value. (See code) This helps when dealing with large numbers in python.

**Slightly Optimized Code :**

```
def foo2(x, y, z, N):

    a = b = c = -1
    i = j = k = -1

    maxProd = 1
    curProd = 1

    for i in range(1, N):
        curProd *= x
        for j in range(1, N):
            curProd *= y
            for k in range(1, N):
                curProd *= z
                if curProd > N:
                    break
                if curProd > maxProd:
                    maxProd = curProd
                    a,b,c = i,j,k

            curProd //= z**k
            if curProd > N:
                break
        curProd //= y**j
        if curProd > N:
            break
    curProd //= x**i

    return a, b, c
```

### Input :

```
x = 4
y = 7
z = 3
N = 21563163762572572574634215165164617645147157
```

Output :

```
(30, 22, 14)
```

### Time Analysis :

Your Implementation : `82 ms`

My Implementation : `14 ms`

### Worst Case :

[image]

Comment: Both algorithms fail to check for minimization of sum of a, b, c.
consider foo(16, 4, 2, 16**2 * 4 * 2 + 1)
algorithm produces (1, 1, 5) which is incorrect.